# Tips on reading undocumented code?

Tags: documentation, teamwork

This summer I got my first position as a programmer (intern), but it has been a disaster. Before the internship they misled me; they didn't tell me they were developing Django apps and told me to just be comfortable with Python (and they expected me to be able to dive right in, and of course I couldn't), and thus I spent the first weeks just learning how Django works and whatnot.

But then came the next problem - reading their code. They have a number of very large, interconnected projects without a *single* piece of documentation. And I mean this literally - the only comments that exist in all the projects are lines of code commented out. No API's no nothing, and so I get lost very easily and therefore can't contribute much to the company.

Any tips on being able to understand undocumented code more easily?

Comment: Why would the answers given in the past not still be valid? Technology might change quickly, but people and their ways of working don't change very much at all. The linked Q has plenty of good answers for you, repeating them is a pointless waste of time, just read those answers.

Comment: "Pride goeth before destruction, and an haughty spirit before a fall"

Comment: It sounds quite frustrating, and I hope that you haven't received any flak from them for the task being difficult, but I wouldn't necessarily call or a disaster.  It sounds like you've had some real world experience.